# Run/Compile Android app in Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, unix

Although I have some experience in Android development, I don't have a lot of experience with linux systems. I have an Android application and I would like to know if it is possible to compile and/or run it on a Linux system. If it is possible, what do I need in order to do so?

Comment: If you want to compile it as an APK, and run it in the AVM, you can do it almost identically as you would do it in windows or mac: rightmouse your project, android, export apk, etc. If you want to compile it for linux native, and run it as a linux program, then it'll be harder.

Comment: @Nanne You might want to put that comment as an answer.  It's a good answer to the question.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636901/can-linux-apps-be-run-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet possible to run android apps on just any linux distribution. But take a look at [the Android-x86 project](http://www.android-x86.org/).

In case I misunderstood your question : if it is about "regular" android development using linux, there are no real issues. Just use your favorite IDE.

You may need to read [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) to be able to deploy and debug on your device using USB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless I misunderstand. The computer I work on is running Ubuntu 11.10 Linux distribution. You can just download eclipse and get the plugins or do you want to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse, the ADT-Plugin and the Android-Emulators all work fine in Debian based distributions.
Probably also on most other like Red Hat or openSuse,.....