# C++ library for android

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I have written multiple apps in eclipse using the SDK. I have also worked with C++ before. Now I am being asked to arrange for some old C++ code to be wrapped up into a java library, or at least have a java interface, such that other android programmers (with no knowledge of C++) can employ it in their code.

I have seen a variety of examples and discussions of making C++ code into complete stand alone apps using the NDK, but never a library.

It would be even better if the android programmer that uses my library didn't even need to know about, or install, the NDK themselves.

Can someone confirm that what I am trying to do is even possible. And if so, how?

Comment: Can't you just provide the lib compiled for whatever ARM you're targeting and use the JNI to interface with it? I know for a fact that c4droid can install SDL and Qt so it must be possible to use precompiled libs. Also, you might take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Comment: It is possible. There is a difference between possible and easy. [This](http://www.xwt.org/mips2java/) may be helpful.

Comment: This is definitely possible. The whole purpose of the NDK is to allow native code (C++) to interface with the Dalvik VM. Do you know which platform you're targeting? You'll need to cross-compile the native code.

Comment: @bblincoe: Puzzled by "Do you know which platform you're targeting" - I'm targeting the full variety of android phones and tablets - did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @Mick When I say platform I mean architecture (ARM, for example). Check out this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071204/android-ndk-vs-cross-compile-both-work-what-was-the-need-of-android-ndk-then

Comment: I have now edited the question to conform to SO policy - can it please be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) (Java Native Interface) code to access the library. In your Java class you will have a method such as:

```
private native final int doStuff();
```

which will correspond to a function in a .cpp file compiled with the NDK. This C++ function will be called when the Java method is called.

Take a look at this article: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/

Here is an open source project in which I am doing this very thing: https://github.com/svenoaks/SoundTouch-Android. Take a look at the soundtouch-jni.cpp file and how it corresponds with the calls in the SoundTouch.java file.

After writing the appropriate methods, you can compile your C++ library and JNI code into a binary .so file so users need not know anything about the NDK. The project can then be used like a regular Android library project.

If you want to target x86 devices as well as ARM architecture, you will need to build it with x86 enabled in your Application.mk file - take a look at http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/creating-and-porting-ndk-based-android-apps-for-ia#using-x86-ndk-toolset

Answer (score 1):

There [is a way to do it](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-ndk/u1v64AapyKI) with Eclipse (ADT):

> You could create an android library project and have the developers
>   add that library project to their main project.  Any native libraries
>   in that project will be included into the main project if they have
>   already been built into its lib directory.  It's not a neat as one
>   jar, but it's the same way we do it for regular android library
>   projects that export java code and resources.

For AndroidStudio, the packaging is a bit different, see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/adt-dev/xj51eCWwhFw). Note that AS is currently a moving target; we all hope that it will receive decent support of NDK before it goes official.