# How to use Linux app in android

Tags: android, linux

I have created a app for Linux system. Now I want to developer similarly into Android devices.
I searched everywhere but didn't get result. So please expert which way do i need to use?

Comment: Read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636901/can-linux-apps-be-run-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the [`Android NDK docs`](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). The NDK *(Native Development Kit)* is used to integrate native components into the Android world.

It is based on Makefiles providing you with the ability to build your native components using the provided toolchain.

It is then possible to build your components into different outputs (namely, shared libraries, executables ...).