# Can I install Linux development tools on Android?

Tags: android, c++, linux

If I need a development tool for Android (where Android is the development platform), can I just install the Linux version?

E.g. can I install the Linux version of QtCreator?

Answer (score 2):

> can I just install the Linux version?

No. While Android has a Linux kernel, it lacks most of the Linux userland environment and therefore will not run arbitrary Linux apps, particularly those expecting a Linux UI subsystem like X.

Answer (score 2):

[Can Linux apps be run in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636901/can-linux-apps-be-run-in-android)
Might be helpful. Looks like you might be able to install apps (but maybe not a full IDE).

[QT has a package for Android](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/android-support.html) though. So you might be able to get some of the things you want.